# Making the div follow autoresize textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**PROBLEM** 
I have a comment textarea which i made text responsive thanks to Jack Moores npm package https://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/. Now this all works fine but i have a div which is usually bottom:75px; and when textarea autoresizes it updates the hight of textarea. This is where the problem occurs i would like to update also bottom of that div for example to keep it from going over textarea.

**HTML**

```
<form action="#">
            <textarea
              type="text"
              id="text"
              spellcheck="false"
              placeholder="Type message..."
              maxlength="50"            
            ></textarea>
          </form>
          <div class="three_dots_messages" onclick="toggleMessagesSettings()"></div>
          <div class="three_dots_messages_menu">
            <div class="three_dots_messages_menu_buttons">
              <div class="send_tip_button all_message_buttons" >
                <span>Send tip</span>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="7.886" height="15" viewBox="0 0 7.886 15"  style="margin: 2px 0 0 2px ;">
                  <path id="Icon_awesome-dollar-sign" data-name="Icon awesome-dollar-sign" class="cls-1" d="M5.731,6.838,2.773,5.912a.861.861,0,0,1-.581-.829A.837.837,0,0,1,3,4.219H4.817a1.6,1.6,0,0,1,.937.308.406.406,0,0,0,.534-.059l.953-1a.5.5,0,0,0-.049-.718,3.716,3.716,0,0,0-2.369-.879V.469A.456.456,0,0,0,4.384,0H3.507a.456.456,0,0,0-.438.469V1.875H3a3.133,3.133,0,0,0-2.985,3.5,3.293,3.293,0,0,0,2.3,2.83l2.807.879a.864.864,0,0,1,.581.829.837.837,0,0,1-.808.864H3.075a1.6,1.6,0,0,1-.937-.308.406.406,0,0,0-.534.059l-.953,1a.5.5,0,0,0,.049.718,3.716,3.716,0,0,0,2.369.879v1.406A.456.456,0,0,0,3.507,15h.876a.456.456,0,0,0,.438-.469V13.119a3.108,3.108,0,0,0,2.9-2.13A3.264,3.264,0,0,0,5.731,6.838Z" transform="translate(-0.003)"/>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class="chat_rules_button all_message_buttons" >
                <span>Chat rules</span> 
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13.125" height="15" viewBox="0 0 13.125 15">
                  <path id="Icon_awesome-book-dead" data-name="Icon awesome-book-dead" class="cls-1" d="M7.969,3.984A.469.469,0,1,0,7.5,3.516.47.47,0,0,0,7.969,3.984ZM13.125,10.5V.75a.69.69,0,0,0-.75-.75H2.813A2.762,2.762,0,0,0,0,2.813v9.375A2.762,2.762,0,0,0,2.813,15h9.563a.739.739,0,0,0,.75-.75v-.469a.81.81,0,0,0-.281-.562,8.292,8.292,0,0,1,0-2.156.567.567,0,0,0,.281-.562ZM7.031,1.641A2.15,2.15,0,0,1,9.375,3.516a1.778,1.778,0,0,1-.937,1.491v.384a.47.47,0,0,1-.469.469H6.094a.47.47,0,0,1-.469-.469V5.007a1.778,1.778,0,0,1-.937-1.491A2.15,2.15,0,0,1,7.031,1.641Zm-3.375,4.9.185-.431a.233.233,0,0,1,.308-.123l2.88,1.233L9.911,5.988a.233.233,0,0,1,.308.123l.185.431a.233.233,0,0,1-.123.308l-2.06.885,2.06.882a.233.233,0,0,1,.123.308l-.185.431a.233.233,0,0,1-.308.123L7.031,8.244,4.151,9.48a.233.233,0,0,1-.308-.123l-.185-.431a.233.233,0,0,1,.123-.308l2.063-.882L3.779,6.85a.233.233,0,0,1-.123-.308Zm7.5,6.583H2.813a.886.886,0,0,1-.937-.937.939.939,0,0,1,.938-.937h8.344ZM6.094,3.984a.469.469,0,1,0-.469-.469A.47.47,0,0,0,6.094,3.984Z"/>
                </svg>              
              </div>
              <div class="muted_users all_message_buttons" >
                <span>Muted users</span> 
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16.071" height="15" viewBox="0 0 16.071 15">
                  <path id="Icon_metro-volume-mute2" data-name="Icon metro-volume-mute2" class="cls-1" d="M18.642,13.15V14.57H17.222l-1.794-1.794L13.634,14.57H12.214V13.15l1.794-1.794L12.214,9.562V8.142h1.421l1.794,1.794,1.794-1.794h1.421V9.562l-1.794,1.794ZM9.535,18.856a.535.535,0,0,1-.379-.157L5.027,14.57H3.106a.536.536,0,0,1-.536-.536V8.677a.536.536,0,0,1,.536-.536H5.027L9.156,4.013a.536.536,0,0,1,.915.379V18.32a.536.536,0,0,1-.536.536Z" transform="translate(-2.571 -3.856)"/>
                </svg>

              </div>
              <div class="close_chat_button all_message_buttons" onclick="toggleMessagesSettings(), toggleMessages() ">
                 <span>Close chat</span> 
                 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15">
                  <path id="Icon_material-close" data-name="Icon material-close" class="cls-1" d="M22.5,9.011,20.989,7.5,15,13.489,9.011,7.5,7.5,9.011,13.489,15,7.5,20.989,9.011,22.5,15,16.511,20.989,22.5,22.5,20.989,16.511,15Z" transform="translate(-7.5 -7.5)"/>
                </svg>            
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .three_dots_messages_menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15%;
  height: 130px;
  min-width: 232px;
  bottom: -250px;
  background-color: #363636;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
    #text {
  border: 1px solid #d4af37;
  background-color: #343333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 13%;
  padding: 12px 30px 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 190px;
  min-height: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  max-height: 100px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}
```

**SOME INFORMATION AND QUESTIONS**

1. I need to keep it position absolute not just fix this with margins.
2. I know i can do this modifying the js of autosize but i am honestly
   not skilled enough to completely understand everything that is going
   on.
3. Is there a way to maybe manipulate the DOM so i can make div children of that textarea ?
4. Do you know maybe easy js fix ?
5. JS for autoresize is too big you can view it from the website

[image: Working fine]

[image: The problem]

Comment: Can you post your code? with snippet possible.

Comment: Can you please add a snipped with your html, css and js. Just use jsfiddle.net to share it. Or paste it as text. In the later option please only paste the code that is relevant to your issue

Comment: @MarcvanNieuwenhuijzen Just added the html and css the JS code for autresize  is too big ~ 225 lines

Comment: @SimoneRossaini added the code and snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best if you simply move the menu to a point before the textarea and remove its fixed positioning, so that it automatically remains in place.

If you want to adapt it dynamically, Autosize triggers an event where you can hook some code to update its position.

```
var $text = jQuery('#text'),
    $menu = jQuery('.three_dots_messages_menu'),
    baseDistance = 75;

$text.on( 'autosize:resized', function() {
  $menu.css( 'bottom', $text.height() + baseDistance + 'px' );
})
```